iOS: Declare tracking if it's disabled completely in third-party SDK
I have an app where I'm integrating the Branch.io SDK which I plan to use only for deeplinks. The SDK provides it's own privacy manifest file with privacy tracking domains defined and some collected data types with "Used for Tracking" set to YES. Does anyone know if I can keep tracking disabled in the App Store Connect - App Privacy section in case if I'll configure the SDK to disable tracking completely without asking users with the ATT permission request?
SDK configuration:
Branch.getInstance().setConsumerProtectionAttributionLevel(.minimal)
Branch.getInstance().disableAdNetworkCallouts(true)

